# Nagios check_mongodb.py returns OK when no mongodb running

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

When running:

```
./check_mongodb.py -H hostname -A connect -P 27017
```

I always get the following response:

```
OK - Connection took 0 seconds
```

within the following situations:

- if the host **is running** mongodb
- if the mongodb **is NOT running**
- and even if **there is no mongodb installed** on the host.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by uninstalling the pymongo 3.2 version and by installing 2.9 version.

pip uninstall pymongo

pip install pymongo==2.9

If you don't have pip, you can instal it as, yum install python-pip (from epel repo)